# Correct way to return a matrix from a function

Tags: c, opencv

I have a function that computes and "create" a matrix. My function works well when it is inlined, but when I try to put the code into a function, I have trouble getting back the result matrix.

I want my function call to be like this :

```
CvMat projectionResult;
project_on_subspace(&projectionResult);
cvShowImage("test", &projectionResult );
```

(Eventually using `*CvMat` instead of `CvMat)

What I did was the following :

```
void project_on_subspace(CvMat * source)
{
source = cvCreateMat( feature_positions[feature_number].height, feature_positions[feature_number].width, CV_32FC1 );    

//some more code
}
```

But the `cvCreateMa`t function changes the value of the source pointer, so when I return from the function, the `projectionResult` matrix is not initialized.

I am aware this is a really easy question, but I don't really understand how to make this work?
Is it possible to do it without changing the function prototype, or do I need to to change it to a `**CvMat` instead of a `*CvMat`?

Edit : I'd prefer to return my result using in an argument pointer, rather than using a "return" statement, but both are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead (assuming cvCreateMat does not return a pointer to a cvCreateMat):

```
void project_on_subspace(cvMat **source)
{
    *source = cvCreateMat(etc...);
    // etc...
```

And call it like:

```
CvMat *projectionResult;
project_on_surface(&projectionResult);
```

Don't forget to deallocate the projectionResult in due time.

Comment: Ok this version works... I'm still wondering if this is the proper way or if I could use only on dereference directly... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`CvMat * source` means that you cannot change the address that `source` points to, but can change the contents of `source`. (Note that you *can* change it, it just won't change for the caller). If you need to be able to change where `source` points to you need to add another level of indirection making `CvMat ** source` which would then allow you to change `*source` and have it effect the calling method.

Comment: Isn't there a way to actually force the header of the matrix I want to create to be placed in the content of source?